# Collapsing toolbar Android define when color transformation to begin

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

do anyone know how to define when the toolbar to start colour transformation from the image to some colour?I mean that the transformations begins when the collapsing is almost done and the image to color transformation is only for few pixels.I want to make it to start from the begging(when the user start collapsing)?